# Eval method returns wrong output

Tags: javascript

eval method of JavaScript return wrong output

```
eval(19 > 0022)
```

the above code returns `true`. Is there any way to fix this.

Thanks for all your comments its fixed now. with these comments

```
const b = '0022'.replace(/^[0]+/g,"");
```

and

`eval(Number('19') > Number('0022'))`

Comment: leading zero numbers could be read as octal numbers.

Comment: Any way to fix it , i have a dynamic string that need to be evaluated.

Comment: And the function expect a sting BTW

Comment: even if condition also allowing true.. it's not a eval problem

Comment: Thanks for lots of comments , but how to deal with this condition. Should i use parseInt

Comment: You can remove the leading zero's using regex. E.g. const b = '0022'.replace(/^[0]+/g,"");

Comment: take `parseInt(value, 10)` with a base of `10`. this ignores the octal default.

Comment: eval(Number('19') > Number('0022')) === false

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobC

Comment: Why are you using `eval` at all? It's needed only when you have a *string* of code - `19 > 022` is an expression that evaluates to a boolean

Comment: Yes @Bergi, i have a string as an expression

Comment: @SandeepBhardwaj Then you should have used that string in your question